# Bug In Reputation Graphs Timeline Labels

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

In my profile's activity page, **the reputation graph shows timeline in such a way that it seems we would already be living at the end of 2020**, even though we are just 1.5 months into the year.

[image]

I noticed some placement issue with the timeline labels already at the start of the year, and since then the time skew has grown much more noticeable.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the reference. It seems that this is the same issue, "off by one year", and additionally the year label for 2020 would also be missing. That sudden spike in my reputation started occuring in December 2019.

I should have researched if there was a similar bug report. But as this was my first bug report in SO, I kind of assumed that this kind of bugs get handled rather promptly. Unfortunately it seems this bug has been reported over a year ago, and has not been addressed even by now.